# Swift correct approach to nil value

Tags: swift, swift3

Reading about Optional values I was sure that all the bases were covered in my code, but I still get the dreaded `unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value`.

That makes sense, since I've read: [What does “fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value” mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32170456). It suggests making the `Int` optional, which is what I want:

```
func myCountUpdate(mainDict: [String : NSObject]) {

    let myDict = mainDict["start"] as! [String : CFString]
    let myCount = subDict["count"] as? String
    let myTotal = Int(myCount)? // nope, it forces me to use non-optional !

    // as the other thread suggest it's easy to check for nil with an optional int.
    // how the hell can you do that if it won't allow you to make it optional?

    if myTotal != nil {
        print(myCount!)
        let label: String = "\(myCount)"
        text = label
    } else {
        text = nil
    }
}
```

I've tried quite a bunch of things, including using other values to check for `nil`, etc. The issue is that the compiler will not allow me to declare the `Int` as non-optional, so what are my options? Xcode shows no warnings or suggestions on this issue, so maybe someone here has one - ty.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value" mean?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32170456/what-does-fatal-error-unexpectedly-found-nil-while-unwrapping-an-optional-valu)

Comment: Read the answers in that duplicate. It explains the proper way to handle optional values. And using `!` is the opposite of what you should be using.

Comment: @rmaddy, The compiler won't let me use anything else though... that's where I'm stuck. I'm not a swift developer and I'm just trying to fix this one thing and move on...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First unwrap the variable optional `myCount`(`String?`) to a variable called `count` (`String`).

```
let myCount = mainDict["count"] as? String

if let count = myCount {
   //..
}
```

Then try to create a `Int` based on the variable `count` (String).

Which could return a nil since you could pass `Int("Hi")` or `Int("1")`.

```
myTotal = Int(count)
```

Then after that you will have a variable called `myTotal` (`Int?`) with the result that you want.

---

## Code

```
func myCountUpdate(mainDict: [String : Any]) {

  let myDict = mainDict["start"] as? [String : Any]

  if let myCount = myDict?["count"] as? String {
    if let myTotal = Int(myCount) {
      print(myTotal)
    }
  }

  if let myCount = myDict?["count"] as? Int {
    print(myCount)
  }

}
```

## Example 1

```
let data = [
  "start": [
    "count": "1"
  ]
]

myCountUpdate(mainDict: data) // outputs 1
```

## Example 2

```
let data1 = [
  "start": [
    "count": 1
  ]
]

myCountUpdate(mainDict: data1) // outputs 1
```

Comment: Maybe an explanation of what you changed in the code could be useful to the OP and others who may come this way in the future. =]

Comment: yea that's good. Just a suggestion so others can get an explanation of what happened. Thanks. I appreciate and I'm sure one day others may too!!

Comment: What does `myDict` do? seems likes it's not being used.. app crashes now too - `unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value`. The error in the code is `Initialization of immutable value 'myDict' was never used; consider replacing with assignment to '_' or removing it`.

Comment: There seems to be another mistake maybe in your code, and that is `subDict`? I don't have that. Also, like the other answer if the value of `myCount` is an integer and not a string it crashes and burns...

Answer (score 3):

The best approach here is to use swift `guards` in order to check if a value is nil.

First, in the second line, where you use the `subDict`, its not referenced anywhere else, should it be `myDict` ?

The thing here is that the cast in `let myCount = subDict["count"] as? String` may be returning nil or there is not "count" in subDict. Therefore, when you do `Int(myCount!)`, the force unwrapp of `myCount` is throwing the exception, since its nil.

You should avoid force unwrappings as much as you can, unless you are 100% sure that the value is not nil. In other cases, you should use the setting of a variable to check if it is not nil.

With your code, an updated version using guard would be the following:

```
func myCountUpdate(mainDict: [String : NSObject]) {
    guard let myDict = mainDict["start"] as? [String : CFString], 
          let myCount = myDict["count"] as? String, 
          let myTotal = Int(myCount) else {
       text = nil
       return
    }

    print(myTotal)
    let label: String = "\(count)"
    text = label
}
```

This is safer, because if any of the conditions in the guard fails, then it's setting the text to nil an ending the method.

Comment: Now it say "Initializer for conditional binding must have Optional type, not 'String'" for the `let count = myCount,` line.

Comment: Sorry, the `let count = myCount` slipped me. `myCount` is not optional actually. I updated the answer!

Comment: Thanks, that sort of worked... (I had to change "count" to "myTotal" - you had two, one still is there), so you might want to fix that in your answer. Another issue is that if the `myDict[count]` value is not a string then it crashes... like if the value is an `Int` it will crash :(`